# Authentication in React/Redux application

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, authentication, redux

I'm relatively new to **redux** and basically to the concept, where front-end separated from back-end. Earlier, i used **laravel** and **RoR** frameworks, where you can actually combine front-end and back-end logic and access back-end code in views. With this approach, it's easy to handle authentication, because frameworks i mentioned above have sessions middleware which gives the possibility to retrieve authenticated user data even after page refresh.

Things changed when you're working with redux. I understand the part **how** to authenticate the user (basically send `POST` request and write data to the store), but how can i handle page refresh, so all the data gets reset by initial state of reducers?

Seems to me that the only way out is to store authenticated user in the localStorage and if it's presistent there - make it an initial state of reducer? Is it safe? Or maybe there are some best practices about this approach?

**[IMPORTANT] Few words about my back-end logic:**

I'm using laravel as a back-end (which basically renders react view with router, where all of the front-end logic are, **if** `url` doesn't starts with **/api**).

I'm **not** using **JWT** or any token approaches, because i have access to all the default middlewares, which gives me possibility to send request with the user data and get **session** identifier as cookies (so each ajax request from react\redux app gets automatically authenticated by laravel).

Comment: If you're using laravel default authentication and then adding the session headers shouldn't the session persist the refresh?

Comment: @SérgioReis the backend is OK, because it automatically reads the session from the cookies. But i'm talking about a front-end. Redux repopulate store according to the initial state of reducers on each page refresh.

Comment: Why not send an http request when first loading to get your user and data when you load? I might just not be understanding the question itself, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

When your app loads and the redux store is initialized you can read from cookies or localStorage and pass the session ID into the preloaded state with redux's `createStore`.

This is enough to initially fetch the user data from the server. Typically this is an async redux action triggered by your root App component's `componenWillMount`.

Whenever the session ID changes, you make sure it's persisted in localStorage, cookies, or whatever you chose.

If you don't want to use `preloadedState` for `createStore`, you can also read the session ID in the initialState of the reducer responsible for auth/user data.

Comment: Now imagine, that you will be sending request for user authentication **every** page refresh, even if the user is not even registered and trying just to reach the part of the site, where be authenticated is not needed..

Comment: No that wouldn't happen, you can serve the app without any auth being done server-side. If the react/redux app can't find a session ID in the persistent storage of the browser, it would prompt the user to log in first.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that laravel creates session for every connection, whether users authenticated or not

Comment: Well if you reload the page, that's a request to the server, regardless of the used js frameworks. Not exactly sure what your question is then.

Comment: Yes, but 1 request, where all the data is processed.

Comment: Ah, you want to hydrate the store with data bootstrapped into the HTML then, so one request is enough to serve the app in an already authenticted state? You would need to render something into the markup as JSON that createStore is reading from then. I would advise against that though. Why is it so important to reducer the number of requests? **One** request more per active user to fetch the user data is really not much in terms of scaling.